# Shiny App Deployment - Error (cannot change working directory)

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to deploy a shiny app using rsconnect: `deployapp(appname = "myapp")`. I get the following message at the command prompt:

> *Application successfully deployed to https://sitename.shinyapps.io/MyApp/*

However, when I launch the app, I get the error message:

> *ERROR: cannot change working directory*

Based on resolution to similar problem on both Stackoverflow and googleforum, I tried using both absolute and relative paths in `setwd()`. Following are the error messages with both absolute and relative paths to `setwd()`:

> Error in setwd("~/Data/Projects/MyApp"): cannot change working directory
>
> Error in setwd("C:/Users/Documents/Data/Projects/MyApp"): cannot change working directory

Any suggestions to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but when you deploy a shiny app aren't you on their servers?? You wouldn't need setwd.. where ever you deployed to would be the wd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

shinyapps.io is a virtualized container service running shiny apps.

1. It is most likely linux based. I do not have the time to write up a
   shiny app to confirm that but like most virtualized containers let
   us assume it is.
2. With 1 being say true. Paths like `C:/` do not make sense in the linux world.
3. Again with 1 in mind the directory structure of `~/Data` might not exist.

Work with relative paths `~/` Also put a checkguard with `dir.exists()` and `dir.create`

```
dirname <-  '~/Data/Projects/MyApp'
if (!dir.exists(dirname))dir.create(dirname,recursive=TRUE)
```

FYI I don't really think your should be doing any `setwd()` for shinyapps. If the data file is is in `~/Data/Projects/Myapp/somedata.csv` you can do a direct read in the app as `read.csv('somedata.csv')`.

The server directory structure is in the form of `/srv/shiny-server/MyShinyApp` when you upload

Comment: thank you folks for your suggestions...looking back I was using the same app file to run locally and to deploy on the server...in hand sight, I should have avoided the setwd() while deploying the app...

Comment: I had the same problem and it was indeed the `setwd()`. I removed it and it worked!

Comment: In my case my home directory is somewhere in the network.. how do I change it to the directory where the files are stored without giving a fixed path?

Answer (score 1):

Error in setwd("c:/nonexistent_directory_path") : cannot change working directory

This error message will be generated when a directory does not exist. Verify that directory does in fact exist (ie: check spelling, typos).